# php mysqli search if found show otherwise say not found

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
    <?php
    $con= new mysqli("localhost","root","","cars");
    $name = $_POST['Search'];

    if (mysqli_connect_error())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cars
     WHERE vin LIKE '%{$name}%' OR license_plate LIKE '%{$name}%'");

if ($result == TRUE) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo $row['year'] . " " . $row['model'] . " " . $row['color'] . " " . $row['license_plate'] . " " . $row['vin'] . " " . $row['reward'];
        echo "<br>";
}


    mysqli_close($con);
    }
    if ($result == FALSE){ echo "car was not found in our database"; }
    ?>
```

**Edit:**

Here is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="search.php" id="Search">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Im trying to have it to where, you type in what you want to find and if it exists then it will show up the details other wise it will say not found and i dont want them to be able to do a blank search and view all of the tables

hope i made this clear to what im trying to do

Comment: `$name = $_POST['Search'];` <= that's what we need more info about.

Comment: Show what your HTML form looks like. This is guesswork, at best. Plus, make sure your DB and table are indeed named `cars`. That's not usually how one works with SQL.

Comment: <form  method="post" action="search.php"  id="Search"> 
    <input  type="text" name="name"> 
 <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
</form> 

and yes the DB is named "cars" and table is also named "cars" dunno if it matters or not

Comment: Here `<input type="text" name="Search">` and not `<input type="text" name="name">` - Problem solved. *You're welcome*.

Comment: OMG!!! YOU FIXDEDEDEDED lol tyvm!

Comment: There you go. You're welcome. Michael should be putting that in his answer. Accept it when he does. You should always post full code when it comes to questions like these. (wink)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, `name="Search"` and `name="search"` are not the same thing ;) Lettercase counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy approach is

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  // if there is more than 0 entry
{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo $row['year'] . " " . $row['model'] . " " . $row['color'] . " " . $row['license_plate'] . " " . $row['vin'] . " " . $row['reward'];
        echo "<br>";
}
}
else  // using an else statement is better than the second if
{
echo "car was not found in our database";
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

**EDIT**

As stated in Fred's comment, change your form to this:

```
  <form method="post" action="search.php" id="Search">
     <input type="text" name="Search"/>
     <input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
  </form>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in D:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\search.php on line 23

Comment: edited it allready, forgot one }, copy it again :)

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Search in D:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\search.php on line 3
2000 z4 black 4t3adg 324135yqergq345g 3000

i didnt type in anything and a result still came up above

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this comment, can you explain

Comment: ok, ex:

lets say 112233 exists in the table as the license_plate and i search 221133 which does not exist in the tables

i do not want any table to show unless 221133 exist and only the rest of the data on that table

Comment: okay, then it will be found if you only enter 1 as license_plate to show this

Comment: ah okay, do you only want stuff to show up if it's entered correct and full?

Comment: and yes, what Fred said in the comment, where does $_POST['Search'] come from and what is your form that is submitting the data?

Comment: My guess is, OP either didn't name the input `name="Search"` or has mispelled it (and/or lettercase), and/or is using GET as the form method. That's why I **never** put in answers for questions like these. Not till I know exactly what I'm dealing with. Questions like these are too much guesswork. But, it stands at getting clearer as the comments go... ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- you'r right, I will do so in the future, too. I'm running in this stuff all the time, as you may have mentionend... :)

Comment: OP isn't responding to my comments. Too many questions to be asked. I suggest you put a form together for the OP, and if he/she says it doesn't match what he/she has, then he/she should show what the HTML form is. I'm moving on... *cheers*

Comment: See you at the next question... :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: [`Problem solved`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598200/php-mysqli-search-if-found-show-otherwise-say-not-found/26598252?noredirect=1#comment41811607_26598200) OP finally responded. Put that in your answer ;)

Comment: Call it a "joint effort". +1 au revoir.

Comment: tyvm fred!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! and micheal!